# How to print a sliced range of numbers list on newline given an input of two numbers

Tags: python-3.x, list, newline, slice

I have a list in range of 1 to 20.

I take input of two numbers `i` and `j` separated by space on single line to slice the list.

Need to print the sliced numbers on newline. I did the following:

```
list_1 = list(range(1,20))
i,j = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

print(list[i:j]);
```

e.g.

Input `10 13`

Output `11, 12, 13`

I want it as [newline_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl0d5.jpg). I tried using `sep='\n'`, but it failed though. What am I missing?

Comment: new line output in the sense.? Should the output start with a new line or end with a new line.?

Comment: Why not just do a for loop and print each number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
list_1 = list(range(1,20))
i,j = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(*list_1[i:j], sep="\n")
```

Comment: Thank you did solve and got to know what was missing. I did use sep but missed i:j. It was like print(*list_1, sep="\n")

Answer (score -1):

```
print("\n".join([str(item) for item in list]));
```

This should give you the output you want.

Comment: This will throw an error because the list of int elements

Comment: you are right, the items in the list need to be converted to a string first, i updated the code sample